# Issue while taking latest from git

Tags: git, github

I have just created a git repository and  been able to check in the code by staging it and then executing the git push. The problem that I am facing is while taking the latest. What I understand is that the directory name in git should match the directory name in your system.

My working folder is C:\Test\MRDB.WEB.UI\

To get the latest i did the following steps
1. Go to the working folder in command prompt
cloned the directory 
2. git clone https://github.com/ranjitmenon/MRDB.git
3. git init
4. git fetch MRDB

When I execute the third step it pulls the all the files into my system with MRDB folder as parent. What I am looking at is that when I execute from the path C:\Test\MRDB.WEB.UI\  only the contents of the file need to get updated in this path. Currently it is adding MRDB folder with files under this path. The other way I am thinking is go one folder up that is C:\Test\ , add a folder in git under MRDB called MRDB.WEB.UI.

I am not sure how to go about it as I am new to git. Please help

Comment: No need of step '3.init' when you cloned a repository. Just 'cd' to go into it. And there, you could work.

Answer (score 1):

So you have listed four 'step' that you have followed

1. Go to the working folder in command prompt cloned the directory
2. git clone https://github.com/ranjitmenon/MRDB.git
3. git init
4. git fetch MRDB

These steps, as listed, are not ones to execute one after another. I encourage you to read the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs) for specific details on those commands.

If I understand you correctly, you want to get 'the latest' off of github. Here is what you do:

1. Go to the folder in your command prompt that you wish to clone MRDB to.

   - `cd C:\Test`
2. Clone your repository

   - `git clone https://github.com/ranjitmenon/MRDB.git MRDB.WEB.UI`

If the directory MRDB.WEB.UI already exists, then I assume the above steps have already been taken. In which case we shall update a previously cloned repository with the latest from github:

1. Go to the folder containing a previously cloned repository

   - `cd C:\Test\MRDB.WEB.UI`
2. Fetch the latest data from github

   - `git fetch origin`
3. Update your local branch

   - `git merge origin/master`

Answer (score 0):

`git init` is done once at the start to setup/create an empty repository. There is no need to re-run it on an existing repository unless you need to [pick up newly added templates or to move the repository to another place](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

Given that you already have an existing repository in Github, you only need to do `git clone https://github.com/ranjitmenon/MRDB.git` on your local directory. This is also only done **once** at the start when setting-up a copy of your repo on your local machine.

I tried cloning your repo and it creates a `MRDB` folder like so:

> E:> git clone https://github.com/ranjitmenon/MRDB.git
>   Cloning into 'MRDB'...
>
> --
>   E:\MRDB
>
> MRDB
>    |- .git
>    |- e2e
>    |- src
>    |- ..other files..

From here, all you need to do is to `cd` to the `MRDB` folder and do all your git operations there. There is no `MRDB.WEB.UI` folder. The top-level folder of your repo is `MRDB`, as shown in Github as "*ranjitmenon/MRDB*".

Now everytime you need to get the latest code changes from your remote repo, you just need to do this in the `MRDB` folder:

> git fetch origin

But `git fetch` only updates your copy of the **remote** branches, which in this case is the **origin/master** branch in Github. It does not update the files on your **local** branches. You can check the difference by doing:

> git log origin/master
>   git log master

From here, to actually update the files on your **local** master branch, you can either do one of the following:

1. `git merge origin/master` (merges the **remote** master to **local** master)
2. `git pull` (combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`)

Note that, if you need some branch other than **master**, you need to do [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) first on that branch, before `pull` or `merge`.

> What I understand is that the directory name in git should match the directory name in your system

`git clone` should already handle matching the directory names (i.e. it created the `MRDB` folder on your local PC to match the `MRDB` folder in Github). What I think is more relevant is that the **branch names** in your local copy should match those in the remote copy.